# Unity3d how to reference swipe control from another script?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, swipe

I have tried every which way possible to get this to work with no success. I have a swipe script and a game/control script. I am trying to reference the swipe control in my control script as the means to control my character. So far I am getting only one error from within Unity.

Assets/RuinRunStarterKit/Scripts/csTempleRun.cs(307,25): error CS1501: No overload for method `UpdatePlayer' takes`0' arguments

I've tried adding TouchDetector.enTouchType within the parenthesis of UpdatePlayer but that gives me three errors rather than just one. I've contacted numerous people and visited numerous sites looking for answers but have failed to yield a working result. I am not educated in programming. I have only researched online to figure out how to do something as far as programming goes. The second script I have here is from an Asset I purchased on the Unity Asset Store. I have contacted them for support for adding swipe controls and they emailed me the touch script but failed to tell me how to implement it. I just want to play this game on my phone with swipe as the controls. This is for personal use. I would really really appreciate it if someone could help me achieve the desired results. Again, I want to be able to control the character using swipe. Thank you. Here are my scripts:

TouchDetector.cs;

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class TouchDetector : MonoBehaviour {
public delegate void deTouchEvent
    (enTouchType touchType);

public static event
    deTouchEvent
    evTouchEvent;

public enum enTouchType
{
    SwipeLeft,
    SwipeRight,
    SwipeDown,
    SwipeUp,
}   

void Start ()
{   
}   

void Update ()
{   
    if (evTouchEvent == null)
        return;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow   )) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeUp   );
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow )) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeDown );
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow )) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeLeft );
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeRight);

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
        {
            Vector3 swipe = t.deltaPosition * t.deltaTime;

            if (swipe.y >  0.5f) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeUp   );
            if (swipe.y < -0.5f) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeDown );
            if (swipe.x >  0.5f) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeRight);
            if (swipe.x < -0.5f) evTouchEvent(enTouchType.SwipeLeft );
        }
    }
}
    }
```

csTempleRun.cs;

```
    void Update () 
    {   
        UpdatePlayer();

        if (m_player != null)
        {
            // Make the camera follow the player (if active)
            SmoothFollow sF = (SmoothFollow)Camera.mainCamera.GetComponent(typeof(SmoothFollow));
            sF.target = m_player.transform;         

            // Check for collisions with interactive objects
            UpdateCoins();
            UpdateMines();

            // Dynamically update the track
            CreateNewCellsIfNeeded(false);
        }       
    }


    private void UpdatePlayer(TouchDetector.enTouchType T)
{
    // if the player is dead (replaced with ragdoll) then exit since none of this code should fire.
    if (m_player == null) 
    {
        return;     
    }



    // Gradually increase the players' running speed, and update the animation to match.
    m_playerRunSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 0.005f;
    m_playerRunSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(m_playerRunSpeed, 0.5f, 3.0f);
    m_player.animation["run"].speed = m_playerRunSpeed * 2.0f;

    // ****************************************************************************************
    // INPUT

    // Player can only turn if they are not already sliding / jumping.  
    // Equally, sliding / jumping are mutually exclusive.

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow)&& m_playerJump <= -1.0f && m_playerSlide <=0.0f)
    {
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.North) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.West;
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.East ) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.North;
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.South) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.East;
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.West ) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.South;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && m_playerJump <= -1.0f && m_playerSlide <=0.0f)
    {
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.North) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.East;
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.East ) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.South;
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.South) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.West;
        if (m_playerDirection == enCellDir.West ) m_playerNextDirection = enCellDir.North;
    }   

    if (T==TouchDetector.enTouchType.SwipeDown && m_playerJump <= -1.0f && m_playerSlide <=0.0f)
    {
        m_playerSlide = 1.0f;
        m_player.animation.Play("slide_fake");
    }            

    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) && m_playerJump <= -1.0f && m_playerSlide <=0.0f)
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(m_jumpAudio, m_player.transform.position);
        m_playerJump = 1.0f;
        m_playerYvel = 0.0f;
        m_player.animation.Play("jump");
    }
```

I hope I'm not doing anything wrong by posting this script but I feel I need to post this in order to get the help I need. You'll notice in the csTempleRun.cs script that I replaced one of the KeyCode calls with TouchDetector.enTouchType.SwipeDown. Yet I am still getting an error. Thank you in advance for anyone's help. Thank you for your time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your error - `No overload for method UpdatePlayer' takes0' arguments`. It means that you need to supply an additional data to your method. Which data you need to supply intellisense can tell you.

Comment: Dude, you can press '-1' button 100 times, if you even can't read  compiler message, what should I talk to you? Read books...

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
void Update () 
{   
    UpdatePlayer(); 
    ...
```

You call `UpdatePlayer()` with zero arguments. However, `UpdatePlayer` needs an argument:

```
private void UpdatePlayer(TouchDetector.enTouchType T)
{
```

So, when you call `UpdatePlayer()`, you need to send an object of the type `TouchDetector.enTouchType` as parameter. That would be one of the following:

- SwipeLeft
- SwipeRight
- SwipeDown
- SwipeUp

Comment: I think I understood you correctly. I moved the TouchDetector.enTouchType T to the first call of UpdatePlayer() within the Update() method but that gave me multiple errors. I need to use all four swipe directions.